# Regex does not capture characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I want my Regex to ignore the string if it contains two *s instead of one *:

```
**hello**
*hello*
```

My Regex captures two `*hello*`s. How can I only capture the `*hello*` and not the `**hello**`?
Here's my current Regex:

```
\*{1}?[^\*|\s]{1,}?\*{1}?
```

Edit: What I'm trying to do:
I am making a Chrome extension that turns `*hello*` into *hello* and turns `**hello**` into **hello**. However, because the Regex makes `**hello**` overlap with `*hello*` it turns what is meant to be bold into italics. How can I stop that?

Comment: What about `**hello*` and `*hello**`?

Comment: That's not a problem. I can deal with them. They do not capture wrong.<br>

Comment: But what should be captured? `hi*hello*` ?

Comment: pressed enter by mistake - I am trying to make something that turns text into bold with `**hello**` and turns `*hello*` into italics. Instead it turns the bolds into italics because they overlap.

Comment: The *hello* part is captured. Explained what im trying to do above ^

Comment: Why don't you just search for `**hello**` first, then search for `*hello*`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key when doing this is to replace `\*\*([^*]*)\*\*` with `<b>\1</b>` *and then* replace `\*([^*]*)\*` with `<i>\1</i>`, or strong/em, css styles, whatever you're actually using to change the font.

To cover i's nested within bold tags, (the reverse is a non-issue), you can use this for your boldifying regex: `\*\*([^*]*(\*[^*]*\*[^*]*))\*\*`

Comment: Essentially matching all the specific expressions first and keep the most generic (that would match more than one string) as last.

Comment: I was hoping for a little more efficiency with the regex, but I'll just accept this. I did think about doing this but it wasnt *exactly* what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
[^*]\*([^\*\s]+)\*($|[^*])
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tC0lJ0/3)

Comment: So close! I would like the `*hello*` inbetween the two "h"s to match. https://regex101.com/r/tC0lJ0/2

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for "if it contains";  Try this:

```
var contains = "**hello**".indexOf("**")>=0;
// 'contains' is true if '**' exists in the string.
```